# Display ByteArrayContent in Angular

Tags: angular, image

I am having Web API which is two years old and don't want to make changes as it is working fine in existing Knockout and polymer applications.

I am trying to work with angular and wants to display this image.

Here is my API Code

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetResponse()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(this.Data);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        return response;
    }
```

when I go to http://localhost:6060/designs/42698 in the browser it display image. No issues.

When I am trying to access this in angular using the below code, I am getting error as shown in attached image [image]

```
this.service
  .getImage(this.id)
  .subscribe(
    (baseImage: any) => {
      if (baseImage !== null) {
      const objectURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + baseImage.image;
      this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
      } else {
        this.image  = '../assets/images/placeholder.png';
      }
    },
    error => {
      this.errorMessage = error.error;
    }
  );
```

Here is getimage code

```
 public getImage(id: number) {
const url = `http://localhost:6060/designs/42968`;
return this.http.get<any>(url)
  .pipe(catchError(error => this.errorHandler(error))); }
```

**I can see the image in Network tab in chrome developer tools but still throwing error.**

After adding response type as blob, I am getting the data as attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: what is getImage response type?

Comment: any is response type

Comment: use response type blob like this `this.http.get<any>(url, {responseType:"blob"})`. It should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your image data to a dataURL:

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = (e) => this.image = e.target.result;
fileReader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([Data]));
```

And also make sure you set the responseType to be of type `blob` in your `getImage()` service like @vsoni mentioned. It should looks like this:

```
public getImage(id: number) {
   const url = `http://localhost:6060/designs/42968`;
   return this.http.get<any>(url, { responseType: "blob" })
     .pipe(catchError(error => this.errorHandler(error))); 
}
```

Than you can display the image like this:

```
<img [src]="image"/>
```

**EDIT:**

Try this one:

```
reader.onload = function() {
   console.log(reader.result)
   this.image = reader.result;
};

reader.readAsDataURL(yourBlobFileFromServerHere);
```

Comment: Hi, After changing the responsetype to blob, I am not getting that error but I encountered different error. I attached the screenshot to my above question. Your code, e.target.result is throwing compilation error

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do
pass your response `blob` file

```
 var reader_data = new FileReader();
 reader_data.readAsDataURL(your_blob_file); 
 reader_data.onloadend = function() {
     var base64data = reader_data.result;                
     console.log(base64data);<--- this returns base64
     this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(base64data);
 }
```